# Core Animation Instrument for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, core-animation, instruments

For tuning the performance of an application, the Core Animation Instrument is a very useful tool for iOS developers. The layer colorization helps find potential bottlenecks quickly, and getting an FPS graph can be helpful as well.

Unfortunately, this Instrument seems to be unavailable for Mac apps.

Is there an alternative, or am I just not looking hard enough (*Advanced Mac OS X Programming* by Mark Dalrymple does mention the Instrument)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some tools can be found here:

- Menu Xcode > Open Developer Tool > More Developer Tools …
- Will open developer.apple.com and you'll have to sign in
- Download "Graphics Tools for Xcode - January 2013"

Then use "Quartz Debug" for a Frame Meter.

There are also some Environment Variables for debugging CALayers:

```
CA_COLOR_FLUSH, CA_COLOR_NO_WAIT, CA_COLOR_OPAQUE, CA_LOG_IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS, CA_LOG_IMAGE_COPIES, CA_COLOR_COPY, CA_PRINT_OBJECTS, CA_COLOR_OFFSCREEN
```

Those are sadly not documented, here you'll find a list of those:
http://www.iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/QuartzCore.framework

Comment: Update for 2019: Quartz Debug is now found with the same steps, but instead download "Additional Tools for Xcode 11" for modern Xcode versions